# How do i use labels that are in Form1 dsigner at the new class?

Tags: c#

For example in my new class i have this:

```
if ((connectionStart[f] == i && connectionEnd[f] == j) || (connectionStart[f] == j && connectionEnd[f] == i)) // this checking dosent work good !
                {
                    //button2.Enabled = false;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    /*label12.Text = connectionStart[f].ToString();
                    label11.Text = connectionEnd[f].ToString();
                    label9.Visible = true;
                    label10.Visible = true;
                    label11.Visible = true;
                    label12.Visible = true;*/
                }
```

Marked them with /* and */ for now

But how can i use them also the button2 so it will take effect when running the program ?

I cant make the button or labels static in Form1 since they are in the designer and i dont want to use static.

And i dont want to create Form1 instance.

I also want to build for all the labels,buttons and other objects like that some function/s in the class so i can use them easy and so they will take effect when im running the program.

For now they are not exist in the new class that clear.

** Maybe to create a property in Form1 for all this objects so i can use them easy in the new Class ? **

Comment: You can't modify the values of a form without creating an instance of a form.  Form1 is not static so you cannot treat it like it is.

Comment: Use events to avoid putting UI implementation details into non-UI related classes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all these controls are placed on some form which is already instantiated. So you need to provide instance of this for in your new class (ctor, property, method, etc).

Then in the form class you need to open access to the controls instances (because they are private or protected by default) via public property or methods.

Then you can access controls in the your class like:

```
public class MySecondClass {

    private MainForm mainForm;

    public MySecondClass(MainForm mainForm) 
    {
        this.mainForm = mainForm; 
    }

    public void SomeFinctionOfNewClass()
    {
        this.mainForm.Label10.Text = "Some text for label"; // it's using property
    }
}
```

As an option 2 you can create an event in the your new class and subscribe to it in the form class where you have access to the controls. Then using event arguments you can provide settings of the controls to the even handler. In this case you will not open access to the controls from any other place then form class.